# How to encrypt and decrypt integers?

Tags: java, security, encryption

Is it possible somehow translate integer into a string of random numbers and chars?
For example:

```
Integer i=1;
String genStr=generateString(i);
```

`genStr` will be something like this`WxmFbBirXVaQ2VnN2s`after generating.
Then I need to convert `genStr` back into number.Something like this:

```
i=backToInteger(genStr);
```

So basically i need 2 functions: encryption and decryption

I need it after tagging my files with each unique id.
When i send this id to the controller that what i want to be desplayed:
`https://localhost:8080/MyController/open?id=WxmFbBirXVaQ2VnN2s` 
So later i can decrypt my `id` in `MyController`
 Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: What level of security do you require? Just something to keep hoodlums from reading the data (e.g. obfuscation is OK), or do you need full on encryption/decryption? Also, if you're looking for full encryption, what are your requirements for the keys? Is the person decrypting always the one who encrypts, or is this for transmitting a message between two parties securely?

Comment: Use Java encryption: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#SimpleEncrEx

Comment: I don't see why you need encryption at all. Just generate a random token and put it into an additional column in your database.

Comment: Artjom B.,maybe you are right, I will pass simple number instead

Answer (score 0):

You could just append session id to the number i.e. sessionId_num to convert it to String before applying encryption. During decryption, if the session id don't match, reject the request. This could minimize replay attack.